# How to prevent the Time conversionBy ui:inputDateTime component in lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, timezone

I need to diplay the date and time in ui:inputDateTime component in lightning, But somehow the ui:inputDateTime component is internally converting the time into local time zone. I want to prevent it from conversion.

For example :

```
<ui:inputDateTime aura:id="pickup_date_time" value="2017-11-03T15:30:00" displayDatePicker="true" class="slds-input" />
```

it is showing the Time
[image]

I just want to show the exact time which is being passed into the component.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Date difference is more than 2 days how it's possible? `2017-11-03T15:30:00` & `01-Nov-2017` in the date field.

Comment: yes man @itzmukeshy7 That is the peroblem.